# Python3.7 cant use import SimpleJson

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, simplejson

I am using python3.7 with `import simplejson`, but I got error `Unresolved import: SimpleJson`, I tried to `pip install simplejson`,

```
Collecting simeplejson
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simeplejson (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for simeplejson
```

Then I tried `pip install SimpleJson`, it is ok:

```
Collecting SimpleJson
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/24/c35fb1c1c315fc0fffe61ea00d3f88e85469004713dab488dee4f35b0aff/simplejson-3.16.0.tar.gz (81kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 194kB/s
Installing collected packages: SimpleJson
Running setup.py install for SimpleJson ... done
Successfully installed SimpleJson-3.16.0
```

But I still got error `Unresolved import: SimpleJson`, what can I do next? By the way, I used `simplejson.loads()` in my code.

Comment: If you have several Python versions, try `pip3 install SimpleJson` or `/path/to/pip3.7 install SimpleJson`. Or if you're using PyCharm: File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Select Python 3.7 -> + -> Search for "SimpleJson" -> Install Package

Comment: Do `import simplejson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleJson` is the package's distribution name. When you actually import it you should `import simplejson` instead of `import SimpleJson`.